# Clean up after shell script that is run via k8s pod on a gpu node for health check

Tags: bash

Team, 
I have a working script but when we upgraded some drivers on the GPU system it’s starting to cause zombie process and system is lowing down as script runs periodically as a crib job.

so I am trying to see is there a way I can have a graceful clean up after the Scripts run what is the best procedure to clean up after yourself when Scripts is done running? What wrong am I doing or what better could it be?

```
gpu-health-check.sh: |
     #!/bin/bash
     # Do nothing if nvidia-smi is found. This is not a GPU node.
     if ! [ -x "$(command -v nvidia-smi)" ]; then
       echo "nvidia-smi not found. Ignoring"
       exit 0
     fi
     # Check if there is any retired page. The query is copied from https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/dynamic-page-retirement/index.html.
     bad_gpus=$(nvidia-smi --query-retired-pages=gpu_uuid,retired_pages.address,retired_pages.cause --format=csv,noheader | cut -d, -f1| sort | uniq)
     if [ -z "${bad_gpus}" ]; then
       echo "No Single/Double Bit ECC Error found"
       exit 0
     fi
     for bad_gpu in "{$bad_gpus}"; do
       # Exit 1 if there is a pending page blacklist as we need to reboot the node to actually add the page to the blacklist.
       nvidia-smi -i $bad_gpu -q -d  PAGE_RETIREMENT | grep Pending| grep Yes > /dev/null 2>&1
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "Found pending blacklist on ${bad_gpu}"
         exit 1
       fi
       echo "No pending blacklist on ${bad_gpu}"
     done
     exit 0
```

On gpu system I see

```
741:19286 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
757:30022 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
761:31930 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
762:31931 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
794:37947 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash ./config/gpu-health-check.sh
795:37948 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash ./config/gpu-health-check.sh
796:37955 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash ./config/gpu-health-check.sh
803:37962 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash ./config/gpu-health-check.sh
816:50066 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
817:50067 ?        Z      0:00 [gpu-health-chec] <defunct>
```

All above are just piling up. How to avoid coz system is becoming irresponsible after hours.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash
> ```

Why not plain `/bin/sh`?  I don't see any non-POSIX shell constructs in there.

> ```
> sort | uniq
> ```

We could replace with `sort -u` (that's a standard option).

> ```
>      echo "Found pending blacklist on ${bad_gpu}"
>      exit 1
> ```

That message should go to standard error stream: `>&2`.  The same *may* be true of the other informational messages.

> ```
>  for bad_gpu in "{$bad_gpus}"; do
> ```

Really?  `"{$bad_gpus}"` is a single token; I think you meant `$bad_gpus` there.  Especially as we then expand `$bad_gpu` unquoted in the next line.

> ```
> grep Pending| grep Yes > /dev/null 2>&1
> ```

If `Pending` and `Yes` always occur in the same order, we could simplify to a single command (and we don't need the redirection):

```
grep -q 'Pending.*Yes'
```

> ```
>    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

That's an antipattern - it's a sign that you need to move the preceding statement into the `if`:

```
if nvidia-smi -i "$bad_gpu" ...
then
```